# Excel Formula Help: If cells are blank then xyz

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets

Help with a formula based on the below criteria:

```
If cells I and J are blank then K = "Initiated" 
If cell I has a date and J is blank then K = "Invited" 
If cells I and J have a date then K = "Complete"
```

How would I go about writing this formula - I believe I would start with something like the following - however, this just returns an error

```
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(I2));NOT(ISBLANK(J2)));IF((I2&J2="";"Initiated";"Invited");"Complete"))
```

Comment: "_ this just returns an error_" and whats the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter this formula in Column K,

```
=IF(AND(I1="";J1="");"Initiated";IF(AND(I1<>"";J1<>"");"Complete";"Invited"))
```

[image]